# Lose some FDs in 2nf normalization?

Tags: normalization

Suppose we have R=(A,B,C,D) and FDs are {B->C, C->D}. The only candidate key is AB, then A and B are prime; C and D are not prime.
B->C breaks the 2NF requirements because is a partial dependency. So we break the relation into R1(A,B,D) and R2(B,C). But now C->D is lost! Am I wrong? So this breaking is not "good"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the breaking is not good.

The reason is that you FDs (`B->C` and `C->D`) also imply `B->D`. So `B->CD` (both `B->C` and `B->D`) break 2NF and should be used for the table breaking.

So, the relations, in order to be 2NF should be: `(A,B)` and `(B,C,D)`.

(and then the `C->D` can be used to break the second further for 3NF.)